# Trim white space from array values

Tags: postgresql

My records in the table are as follows:

```
id    column1
 1   'Record1'
 2   ' Record2'
 3   ' Record3a, Record3b'
 4   'Record4a , Record4b, Record4c '

column1 type: text
```

**`pre-defined array= {record1,record2,record3a}`**

While I'm checking the values with a pre-defined array using **&&** operator, most of the values are missed because of the delimiter space between those which are unnecessary.

Hence I need to first remove these space that are there in beginning or end (only) and then do ***string_to_array()*** so that the result could be compared to my pre-defined array

Comment: Can you include the actual query and table definition(s) ?

Comment: @TimBiegelesien I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [trim()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) to remove leading a trailing whitespace:

```
SELECT string_to_array(trim(both ' ' from regexp_replace(column1, '\s*,\s*', ',')), ',')
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Nah @Tim Biegeleisen... I just ran it for ' Record3a, Record3b', it gave: {Record3a," Record3b"}... which is incorrect since the second element still contains a trailing space

Comment: Wait...are those quotes actually part of the data?

Comment: No... that isn't the part of the data.... that came as an output.... it is simply: {Record3a, Record3b}

Comment: Again, are those _brackets_ part of the actual data?

Comment: Your logic just removed the space at beginning and end of the text field... But if it is between two comma separated tags, then those spaces are not being considered. Your logic is doing:' Record3a, Record3b'==> 'Record3a, Record3b'

Comment: those brackets represent array. I added it represent the datatype

Comment: Is `column1` string or array?

Comment: column1 is text

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi I have updated my answer.  You can first use a regex to clean up the separation of terms in your column, then trim it and convert to an array.

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi `E'\\s*,\\s*'` or `'\s*,\s*'`

Answer (score 2):

> SELECT string_to_array(trim(both ' ' from regexp_replace(column1,
> '\s*,\s*', ',')), ',') FROM yourTable

It works, but the 'g' flag should be added to remove all whitespaces:

```
SELECT string_to_array(
   trim(both ' ' from regexp_replace(column1, '\s*,\s*', ',')), ',','g')
FROM yourTable
```